# How are edits and flags handled during private beta?

Tags: support, editing, beta-phase, review, flagging

*To the StackExchange team, or to people who've been there, done that, and know how it works:*

During the private beta, how are suggested edits peer-reviewed, and who handles flags?

Answer (score 4):

So I got an answer from Rebecca on the chat: the SE staff can (and will) handle flags and edit suggestions. Also, users with 500+ rep will be able to review suggested edits.

Answer (score 4):

For the time being, Stack Exchange staff handles flags.

A couple of weeks into the public beta (lose timeline), [moderators](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) will be selected by Stack Exchange staff amongst active users of the site. These moderators are expected to remain in place until a few weeks after the site graduates, then a new moderator team will be elected.

The list of pending suggested edits can be seen by [users with enough reputation](https://french.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) (1000 during the private beta, 2000 during the public beta); they get a notification in the top bar. Anyone with the [privilege to edit](https://french.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit) (500 while private, 1000 when we go public) can review a suggested edit if they happend to see the post.

---

Pour l'instant, c'est le personnel de Stack Exchange qui gère les signalements (*flags*)¹.

Une ou deux semaines après le début de la bêta publique (délai variable), le personnel de Stack Exchange choisira des [modérateurs](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) parmi les utilisateurs actifs volontaires. Cette équipe de modérateurs demeurera en principe en place jusqu'à ce que le site entre en phase de fonctionnement normal, ensuite les modérateurs seront élus par les utilisateurs.

Pour ce qui est des modifications proposées¹ (*suggested edits*), les utilisateurs qui ont une [réputation suffisante](https://french.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) (1000 pendant la bêta privée, 2000 pendant la bêta publique) ont accès à la liste, et voient une notification dans la barre en haut de page. Tout utilisateur qui a la [permission de modifier des messages](https://french.stackexchange.com/privileges/edit)¹ (500 pendant la bêta privée, 1000 pendant la bêta publique) peut accepter ou rejeter une proposition de modification s'il tombe sur le message en question.

¹ 
<sub>Si vous avez une meilleure traduction…</sub>