# Convention for indicating you'd like an ancillary translation

Tags: discussion, language

What I mean is: I'm asking a question about topic A, during the course of which I use word which I'm not too happy with. I don't want it to become the topic of my question, and it's probably not worth a question of its own, but I *would* like to indicate that I'm aware that the word is sub-optimal, and that I'm open and eager for suggestions/corrections.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

I quite like what Gilles did [here](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63/how-are-edits-and-flags-handled-during-private-beta/66#66), using something like this<sup>1</sup> to indicate this.

<sup>1</sup> I'm open to suggestions.

In this case, for me it would be quite acceptable for someone to step in, and edit directly. That way *I'd* be notified of the edit (I believe). The only thing is that nobody else would benefit from this little nugget of wisdom. Maybe that's not a big deal?

Of course, ideally we could agree on a convention which would obviate the need for the actual footnote, and just have something like this<sup>#</sup>.

Comment: Maybe when editing to suggest a better word, we should take the habit to just strike the old word rather than removing it altogether?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple solution: put a question mark between parentheses after the word.

> La porte n'est pas ouverte ; elle est donc close (?).